# Any ideas on how to automatically georreference thermal imagery? (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, qgis, geo

I'm spending some time trying to solve a problem about georreferencing thermal imagery. Right now my test corresponds to thermal images of photovoltaics but i'm looking for export it to different kind of images.

I'm working with images taken by drone like this:

[Thermal image in Rainbow HC palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cENFM.png)

In the other part I got a pretty decent quality RGB orthomosaic already georreferenced:

[Rgb Orthomosaic (about 2px/cm gsd)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVMd.jpg)

I would like to automatically georreference the thermal image into the RGB by software. Assuming that the thermal image is already georreference (poorly because it uses the gps position of the drone) I think there should be some way to perfect fit the thermal image into the RGB one. Example of what i'm talking about:

[Thermal image is 50% opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjDG8.jpg)

I failed trying to use kind of feature detection algorithm and using object detection for indetify the solar panels (besides this approach won't work in other kind of images). I'm looking for a more robust tool.

I'm working in python.

I tried feature detection with different opencv algorithms for matching the two images but I'm not getting acceptable results:

[Failed feature matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7KmT.jpg)

Maybe there is a feature detection algorithm that works better for this kind of imagery?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider using feature matching with SIFT or ORB. Then get the homography and do a perspective warp to align the one image with the other. See https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html